# Onabort event in javascript and document abort

Tags: javascript

Can I somehow find out if user abort document downloading ? I think, I can somehow use onabort event, but i don't how, because onabort is only for images. Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'user abort document downloading', do you mean 'clicking on the cancel button (or similar) on a download you gave the user?

Comment: onabort isn't part of any standard and IE only supports it for images.

Comment: I mean clicking on the cancel button.